# Is it possible to use sessionauth of martini with Datastore on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, session, go, google-cloud-datastore, martini

I tried to use the example of [sessionauth](https://github.com/martini-contrib/sessionauth) of [martini](https://github.com/go-martini/martini) on google app engine and want to save login list in Datastore, but did not know how to deal with appengine.Context. Does anyone has the experience?

Thank you.

Update:

```
// Auth example is an example application which requires a login
// to view a private link. The username is "testuser" and the password
// is "password". This will require GORP and an SQLite3 database.
package ahl

import (
    //"fmt"
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "github.com/hnakamur/gaesessions"
    "github.com/martini-contrib/binding"
    "github.com/martini-contrib/render"
    "github.com/martini-contrib/sessionauth"
    "github.com/martini-contrib/sessions"
    "net/http"
)

//var namespace string = "ahl"

func init() {
    //store := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret123"))
    store := gaesessions.NewDatastoreStore("", gaesessions.DefaultNonPersistentSessionDuration)

    m := martini.Classic()
    m.Use(render.Renderer())

    // Default our store to use Session cookies, so we don't leave logged in
    // users roaming around
    //store.Options(sessions.Options{
    //  MaxAge: 0,
    //})
    m.Use(sessions.Sessions("my_session", store))
    m.Use(sessionauth.SessionUser(GenerateAnonymousUser))
    sessionauth.RedirectUrl = "/new-login"
    sessionauth.RedirectParam = "new-next"

    m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) {
        r.HTML(200, "index", nil)
    })

    m.Get("/new-login", func(r render.Render) {
        r.HTML(200, "login", nil)
    })

    m.Post("/new-login", binding.Bind(MyUserModel{}), func(session sessions.Session, postedUser MyUserModel, r render.Render, req *http.Request) {
        // You should verify credentials against a database or some other mechanism at this point.
        // Then you can authenticate this session.
        //user := MyUserModel{}
        user := MyUserModel{1, "testuser", "password", false}
        //err := dbmap.SelectOne(&user, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1 and password = $2", postedUser.Username, postedUser.Password)
        //if err != nil {
        //  r.Redirect(sessionauth.RedirectUrl)
        //  return
        //} else {
        err := sessionauth.AuthenticateSession(session, &user)
        if err != nil {
            r.JSON(500, err)
        }

        params := req.URL.Query()
        redirect := params.Get(sessionauth.RedirectParam)
        r.Redirect(redirect)
        return
        //}
    })

    m.Get("/private", sessionauth.LoginRequired, func(r render.Render, user sessionauth.User) {
        r.HTML(200, "private", user.(*MyUserModel))
    })

    m.Get("/logout", sessionauth.LoginRequired, func(session sessions.Session, user sessionauth.User, r render.Render) {
        sessionauth.Logout(session, user)
        r.Redirect("/")
    })

    http.Handle("/", m)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. The sessionauth package requires you to pass it a `*sessions.Store`, and there is a gaesessions package that can replace the default cookie/file stores: https://github.com/hnakamur/gaesessions

The sessionauth package has a full example (https://github.com/martini-contrib/sessionauth/blob/master/example/auth_example.go) - just replace `sessions.NewCookieStore` with `gaesessions.NewDatastoreStore`.

Comment: It seems not as easy as what you said. The gaesessions can not be the replacement of https://github.com/martini-contrib/sessions. I guess I need to write sessionauth for gae datastore by myself and share, right? Hope I will succeed.

Comment: Both sessionauth and contrib/sessions accept a *sessions.Store. Can you provide the code and/or errors you are getting (update your question) so we can debug it? There does not appear to be any reason why you can't use an alternative session store (and worst case, the CookieStore will work).

Comment: Please see the post Update. The example runs different from original one. I can not login anymore.
Okay, I guess I misunderstand something about sessions, because this is my first time writing a web server. I see in user.go, the GetById function, the comment reminds us to have a login list and check user id from that list, so I guess I need to save the login list in Datastore. But to access Datastore, I need to pass http.request to GetById to run appengine.NewContext, and I stuck, so I post here.

I guess I just don't need to write login list in the datastore.
Thanks anyway.